# Should entity hold reference to repository?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Suppose we have `class Home` and we want to have collection of all `Cats` inside this home, but also we want to have general repository of `Cats` that has all the cats available in the world. Should `Home` hold the reference to specific repository (or maybe collection) of `Cats`, or should I just make another lookup in general repository?

Answer (score 3):

From a domain-driven design perspective you shouldn't have one aggregate root (AR) instance contained in another AR instance and typically one also would not have a reference to a repository in any entity.

So if `Home` and `Cat` are both ARs then `Home` should contain only a list of `Cat` Ids or a list of value objects (VO) that each represent a cat, e.g. `HomeCat` that contains the `Id` and, perhaps, the `Name`.  This also facilitates the persistence around the `Home` AR since the `HomeRepository` will be responsible for persistence of both `Home` and `HomeCat`.

I must admit that this is where an `Entity` such as `Cat` becomes somewhat of a weird thing when it is contained in more than one AR.  However, you would still not have the cat repository in the home object but rather have the `HomeRepository` make use of the `CatRepository` when retrieving the relevant home instance.

Comment: Why would you need a collection of ids in `Home`? There's no invariant to enforce as far as we know so the collection is kind of pointless. The relationship should usually be modeled from the many-to-one side, therefore `Cat` would reference it's `Home` by identity. Using `CatRepository`, you can easily find all `Cat`s of a specific `Home`.

Comment: That is going to depend on the domain, unfortunately.  Since this does resemble a fictitious domain I gave a couple of options.  The OP did mention that there is a collection of cats in the home so there is some sort of relationship.

Comment: I'm only saying that you can achieve the same relationship without the collection. We obviously do not know enough of the domain to know for sure, but from what we know maintaining a collection is superfluous and was probably modeled this way because bad ActiveRecord-like habits ;) If you do not need the collection to enforce some invariants from the Home's perspective then it shouldn't be there or it puts artificial constraints in the model and greatly harms scalability, because now two simultaneous transactions adding a cat to the same home will fail for no reason.

Comment: Hi @EbenRoux, the app flow you're proposing would be something like: 

1. Petition to the `HomeRepository::getById()` in order to get the desired `Home`
2. The `HomeRepository` gets the `Home` with its collection of `CatId`s value objects
3. The `HomeRepository` makes a petition to the injected `CatRepository` in order to get all the `Cat` instances constructing them as a `HomeCat`

If I understood it well, one question: Doing that, you're coupling one repository to the another, so that the use of the `CatId` value object in the `Home` has no sense because we've no benefit at the end, no? thx!

Comment: Javier, that is going to depend on whether `Cat` is an AR or not.  If it *is* an AR you should *not* have a reference to any `Cat` instances in `Home`.  The VO should ideally contain the invariant bits.  You could, say, call `Home.add(someCatAR)` that internally creates the new VO.  However, if `Cat` is an entity you would need to add it to `Home` somehow and I agree that *that* is somewhat troublesome.  But it is what it is.  I would reconsider the design.  This is probably why most folks feel a repository only returns an AR.

Comment: Thanks for your response @EbenRoux, but I was thinking from the reading side of the application. I mean, I'm interested in which piece of the system has the responsibility to "join" the 2 ARs (the `Home` and the supposed `HomeCat`). Is it the `HomeRepository` by itself? Is it a domain service? Thanks!

Comment: Javier, that gets interesting.  If you are referring to the query side (a la CQRS) then I guess the most appropriate place would be the bit of functionality putting together the query 'view' model.  So all the relevant data would be gathered there, possibly using additional queries to appropriate query layers to get the data.  The structure of the, say, initial event such as `HomeAddedEvent` would still only contains the cat Ids and the processor would then get the relevant cat data using the `CatQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

As Java is based on references, you could keep two collections without any serious harm.

What you need is to assure is that every cat on your home is also in the "world". The problem here is if the cats on your home change a lot, you would need to make several lookups, so you should choose a data structure data enables this as fast as you need (i am thinking hashMaps..)

using two collections will enable you to find cats in your home as fast as you can do. however sync-ing the collections might be a problem. in this case you can think about the observer pattern: home observes the world, if a cat dies, it check if it was inside home, and deletes...

there is a lot of way to do what you asked, all you need to do is think about what is the operations with higher frequency, and your need in general. if the collections are small, so no problem on having one collection, with lookups to find the cats home...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer DDD questions with fictional domains (or at least very little information about it), since DDD is all about modeling the domain just the way it is and maintaining the integrity of it's invariants.

As far as I can tell, you do not have any invariant that applies to the relationship between `Home` and `Cat`, therefore you do not need a collection of `Cat` objects within `Home`'s consistency boundary. You could simply have two aggregate roots (`Home` and `Cat`) and `Cat` would reference it's `Home` by **identity**.

You can use the `CatRepository` to query all cats from a specific home or all cats independently of their home.

It's important not to put artificial constraints in the model. For instance, if you hold a collection of `Cat` identities inside `Home` for no other reason than maintaining the relationship, then you are limiting the scalability of your system: two simultaneous transactions trying to associate a new `Cat` to the same `Home` will fail with a concurrency exception for no reason (assuming optimistic concurrency).

Answer (score 0):

If `Cat` needs to be an aggregate root of its own aggregate accessible by a `CatRepository`, then it should **not** be included in the `Home` aggregate.  Your `Home` entity should reference the associated `Cat` entities by identity and not by reference.

This is a question of aggregate design and requires a closer look at your domain and how you need to use your entities. One question you could ask yourself is "if I delete `Home`, should all `Cat` entities be deleted as well?" Do not put too much emphasis on this question. There are other important factors that need to be considered.

Vaughn Vernon covers this topic in his three-part PDF series [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/).

Comment: You should strive to model the relationship from the many-to-one side, therefore Cat would reference it's Home by identity, not the other way around.

Comment: @plalx: That certainly could be a much better approach, but it really depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: However, from what we know holding a collection of cat ids in Home would be wrong as it would greatly harm scalability (more concurrency failures for no reason).